# stacked and grouped bar chart out of HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

I have a set of html tables with numbers in the style like these:

```
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>0:00 - 8:00</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>120</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>8:00 - 18:00</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>18:00 - 0:00</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>60</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>0:00 - 8:00</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>120</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>8:00 - 18:00</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>18:00 - 0:00</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>60</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Check it out at: http://jsbin.com/evakac/7/edit

I want to create a nicely looking visualization of this table with a stacked and simulataneously grouped bar chart directly out of this table.

I have googled a lot, there are a lot of jquery visualization tools out there, but nothing that can do this.

Update: Something like this, directly out of a table would be nice: http://bl.ocks.org/gencay/4629518

Comment: Have you thought about about designing what you want in your graphics program(illustrator, photoshop, inkscape, etc) and just displaying the image?  This doesn't appear to be dynamic anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d3.js offers something similar: http://bl.ocks.org/gencay/4629518

Answer (score 2):

check this one 
[magna charts](https://github.com/alphagov/magna-charta)

demo [here](http://alphagov.github.com/magna-charta/)

may be this helps

Comment: Not bad, but it supports no stacked and grouped bars simultaneously.